# Issue in accessing API/json with multiple sections

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

I'm trying to display all sections of the following JSON file into my reactjs page: https://api.myjson.com/bins/cdres

Below is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {render} from "react-dom";


class apps extends Component {
    
    state = { 
        data: {
            segments: [],
            totals: [],
        }
    }
    
    componentWillMount(){
        fetch('https://api.myjson.com/file', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiR3JlZyIsInVuaXF1ZV9uYW1lIjoiZ2dyYWZmIiwibmJmIjoxNTI0ODM5Nzc1LCJleHAiOjE1MjQ5MjYxNzV9.xhvdfaWkLVZ_HLwYQuPet_2vlxNF7AoYgX-XRufiOj0'
            },
        }
            
    
        ) /*end fetch */
        .then(results => results.json()) 
        .then(data => this.setState({ data: data }))   
      }

      
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return (

                     <div className="clientContainer">
                            
                            {
                                this.state.data.segments.map( item =>( 
                                <div>
                                    <span> {item.clientName} </span>
                                    
                                </div>
                                ))
                            }
                            {
                                this.state.data.totals.map(item =>(
                                    <div>
                                        <span> {item.segmentType} </span>
                                        <span> {item.adjTotalSqrFt} </span>
                                    </div>
                                ))
                            }
                        </div> 
        );
      }
}

export default app;
```

...the code works for consuming data from the segments and totals section of the JSON file, but am having trouble getting the id and username from the top section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an object rather than an array so calling `map` on it triggers an error.

Simply do `this.state.data.segments.map(...)` instead, and change your initial state to

```
state = { data: { segments: [] } }
```

Comment: riwu - thanks, I modified the code I posted, am able to display data from segments and totals sections of the json file. but, how do I get the id and userName, which is located in the top of the json file? thanks

Comment: you can access them with `this.state.data.id`, `this.state.data.userName`.

Answer (score 0):

`map` is a function of `array`. The `data` is an object while `data.segments` is an array. You will need to change the code as below

```
 <div className="clientContainer">
  {
     this.state.data.segments.map( item =>( //change here
     <div>
        <span> {item.clientName} </span>
     </div>
  ))
  }
  </div>
```